# Has a photon or electron ever been observed in a state of superposition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition, subatomic

Has subatomic particles ever been seen in a state of superposition or do we just detect information like qubits about the state of the particle? So is actual matter in superposition or is it just information about matter that's in a state of superposition?

Comment: There really is a sense in which questions like this are fundamentally unanswerable.  It is hard to look at something like quantum interference and not say that the electron was superposed over both slits at one point.  Another great example where it's really hard to say that the electron is not in both places is chemical resonance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0la5DBtOVNI&feature=kp

Comment: One experiment to try is to use polaroid films (which polarize light) and try to see the light through 2 or 3 of polaroids which polarise in different directions or ways (e.g circular polarization, etc..)

Comment: That's my point. Does information tell us that the particle was superposed over two slits because we detect a wave pattern or do we actually see the photon or electron go through both slits? In fact, we can't see it we can just infer it through information. Is that right?

Comment: Start be defining (in precise technical terms, if you please) what you mean by "observed in a state of superposition". Don't worry I'll wait. Or to be more serious, I don't think that the phrase has a meaning in the conventional interpretations of quantum mechanics. You won't be *able* to define it in a way that is consistent with what we think we know about QM.

Comment: @user46759, if "observe" means *measure an observable*, then QM is clear:  one will measure a *definite* value of the observable.  If one measures the position of an electron, the measurement reveals the electron to be *somewhere* and not 'in a superposition of over there and over here' (whatever that may mean if it has meaning at all).  Moreover, immediately after the position measurement, the electron is in a state of definite position and, thus, in a superposition of definite momentum states.  Nonetheless, a momentum measurement will yield one momentum value, not a 'superposition'.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps I do not understand the question. When, for instance, a photon is observed in a state of circular polarization it is simultaneously in a superposition of linear polarization states. Every pure quantum state $\psi$ is always a coherent  superposition of other quantum states eigenstates of observables which are not defined in the state $\psi$. A quantum system stays always in a superposition of states as, in QM, mutually incompatible observables do exist.

Comment: That's my question. When you say "a photon is observed in a state of circular polarization it is simultaneously in a superposition of linear polarization states." How do we know this? Do we actually see the photon in this state or does information tell us it's in this state.

Comment: Mathematically, you can write $\psi_\text{circ} = A\psi_\text{lin 1} + B\psi_\text{lin 2},$ thus we say it's in a superposition.

Comment: @user46759 Just the definition of circular polarization as a quantum observable. Elementary Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: @ValterMoretti: Your statement "Perhaps I do not understand the question" is as foggy as quantum mechanics!! It indicates 'confusion'. Either one understands the question or does not understand the question or understands some part of the question.

Comment: @atom Nope: I accept the theory that consciousness is a quantum phenomenon and thus  I am allowed to have coherent superpositions of thoughts ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> Has subatomic particles ever been seen in a state of superposition

as the other answers state one cannot label an individual particle until measurement of some of its variables. After measurement the information is a specific value of (x,y) or (p,E) at time t.

> or do we just detect information like qubits about the state of the particle?

Just checked what qubits are, but it does not seem to me to be coordinates or four momentum.

> So is actual matter in superposition or is it just information about matter that's in a state of superposition?

Each individual particle has actual mass at detection, i.e. its energy and momentum define it uniquely as the measure of the four vector.

The theory of quantum mechanics predicts the accumulation of measurements as a probability distribution, thus one measurement gives one point in a probability distribution. In the case of the [double slits interferences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles) appear even when one photon at a time goes through.

> So is actual matter in superposition or is it just information about matter that's in a state of superposition?

I see that qubits are [defined as](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit) :

> A qubit is a two-state quantum-mechanical system, such as the polarization of a single photon: here the two states are vertical polarization and horizontal polarization. In a classical system, a bit would have to be in one state or the other. However quantum mechanics allows the qubit to be in a superposition of both states at the same time, a property which is fundamental to quantum computing.

With the mathematics of quantum mechanics this last question is unanswerable, because quantum mechanics only deals with probabilities. There have been and are still on going efforts to get the probabilities from an underlying real system , as with thermodynamics from statistical mechanics, unsuccessfully ( in the sense they are just for specific models, even when successful as in [Bohm mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory)) .  At present the boundary conditions to the quantum mechanical problem determine the solutions where the probability distributions may show interferences, but individual particles appear whole when measured.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, superpositions can be, and have been, observed using [weak measurements](http://www.nature.com/news/physicists-snatch-a-peep-into-quantum-paradox-1.13899).

There seems to be some debate about weak measurement and whether it is really observing a superposed state. This isn't my area so I can't comment. If you're interested in learning more there are a [fair few questions about weak measurement on this site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=weak%20measurement%20is%3Aquestion).

Answer (score 0):

A superposition cannot be measured. Superposition is the state of a particle in the Copenhagen Interpretation of quantum mechanics *before* it is measured. Once you measure/observe it, it is no longer in a superposition.

Comment: This is just nonsense. A superposition is simply a complex linear combination of two states, $a\psi_1+b\psi_2$ etc. A measurement of $L$ brings the physical system to an eigenstate of $L$ but whether it is a "superposition" depends on what $L$ is and on "superposition of what" we talk about (which basis). Generically, the post-measurement state is obviously a superposition. It is not a superposition (or is a trivial superposition) of eigenstates of $L$, one we measured, but it is a superposition of several basis vectors in almost all other bases.

Comment: @LubošMotl I don't think we disagree. We can certainly make measurements that infer that particles are in superpositions, but you can't make a single measurement of a single particle and from that determine that it is in a superposition, precisely because you don't measure superpositions. You measure its collapsed state. Right?

Comment: Probably right, assuming that I understand what you mean.